# How to define the character set of an outbound EDI batch in BizTalk 2010?

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010, edi, edifact

I have some EDIFACT files with a character set of UNOC though lowercase strings and umlaute should be allowed. These files should be batched in an outbound EDIFACT file. But the batching orchestration of the related send port throws some validation errors.

If I convert the strings to uppercase characters everything's working fine. So it seems that the outbound batching orchestration uses the UNOA character set internally for the validation of the EDIFACT files...

How can I change the character set of the outbound batching orchestration in BizTalk 2010? No settings found regarding the character set of outbound batching orchestration in the party and agreement configuration so far. Thank you

Comment: Have you tried checking and changing the EDI Fallback settings to see if this has any effect on the batching orchestration?

Comment: Yes, but doesn't have any impact...